# Graph question about general transformation

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

[image]

The graph above is of an ideal gas in a reversibile transformation. My question is, why is the heat(Q) bigger than 0 from A to 2 and less than 0 afterwards? Can't it be the other way around? (The adiabat. curb is not part of the problem, it is drawn by the book I found the graph in for help)

Comment: See this thread:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/396070/ideal-gas-reversible-cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation for the P-V line you have drawn is:
$$P=P_0\left(1-\frac{V}{V_0}\right)\tag{1}$$where $P_0$ and $V_0$ are the intercepts.

From the 1st law of thermodynamics for this reversible process, we have:
$$dQ=nC_vDT+PdV$$
Combining this with the ideal gas law gives:
$$dQ=\frac{C_v}{R}d(PV)+PdV\tag{2}$$
Substituting Eqn. 1 into Eqn. 2 gives:
$$dQ=\frac{C_v}{R}P_0\left(1-2\frac{V}{V_0}\right)dV+P_0\left(1-\frac{V}{V_0}\right)dV=P_0\left[\left(\frac{C_v}{R}+1\right)-\left(2\frac{C_v}{R}+1\right)\frac{V}{V_0}\right]dV\tag{3}$$
From this equation, we see that dQ/dV = 0 at 
$$\frac{V}{V_0}=\frac{C_p}{C_p+C_v}=\frac{\gamma}{(1+\gamma)}\tag{4}$$
The equation for an adiabat is $PV^{\gamma}=const$.  The derivative of pressure with respect to volume along the adiabat is:
$$\frac{dP}{dV}=-\gamma\frac{P}{V}\tag{5}$$We can find the point $V/V_0$ at which our line is tangent to an adiabat by substituting Eqn. 1 into Eqn. 5.  From this, we find that the point of tangency is when Eqn. 4 is  exactly satisfied.  This is the only point along our P-V line that is tangent to an adiabat.

We then also find that, for $\frac{V}{V_0}<\frac{\gamma}{(1+gamma)}$, $dQ/dV>0$, and for $\frac{V}{V_0}>\frac{\gamma}{(1+gamma)}$, $dQ/dV<0$

Comment: wow thank you very much for taking the time to write thist! Great answer